# How to effectively merge two directories in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, diff

I've tried to use plain `ediff-directories` to make a diff between files but this is very slow because I need to compare files on every nesting level and there are too many of them.

I've also tried `ediff-trees` (defined in [`ediff-trees.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ediff-trees.el)) but that is not convenient either because I don't even see how many files are different and cannot see the picture in general.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Make a fresh git repo. Move in the first dir and commit. Remove everything. Move in the second dir and open `magit`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, abo-abo, but I need not only to make a diff but also apply / merge one dir to another.

Comment: Doesn't matter. magit allows you to do this. Press `k` to undelete a file or delete the diff that you don't like.

Comment: Here is a link to a **two-way** synchronization utility called `Unison`: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/  The `org-mode` manual has a section describing how to use `Unison` with Emacs:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/unison-sync.html  `rsync` is a **one-way** solution and here is a link containing a method for using it in conjunction with `dired-mode`:  http://truongtx.me/2013/04/08/emacs-async-file-copying-with-rsync-update/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package https://github.com/fourier/ztree works nicely for this. Even works over TRAMP.

Comment: Yep, ztree works like a charm! So nice to have a merge tool in Emacs!